# How can I move this logic into controller and is there need for that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok guys I need to ask how can I move this into controller

```
- if UserGroup.where("group_id = ? AND user_id = ?", annoucement.group_id, current_user.id).exists? and annoucement.exp_date >= Date.today
```

It is part of my view and I do not know how to pass values from each to it

```
#Part of index.html.haml

- @annoucements.each do |annoucement|
    - if UserGroup.where("group_id = ? AND user_id = ?", annoucement.group_id, current_user.id).exists? and annoucement.exp_date >= Date.today
      %tr{id: "annoucement_#{annoucement.id}"}
        %td= annoucement.title
        %td= annoucement.description
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely on the right track. Logic like this doesn't belong in the view, and possibly not even in the controller. You want to push the logic 'back', as far as you can, into the controller, maybe into the model. Logic in the view is code smell :D

I believe what you want is a `left_outer_join`. It looks like `UserGroup` is a join table between Users and Groups, right? If that's the case, then the naming convention would be `UsersGroup`. I'm going to work on this assumption. My code may not match what you've got, so adjust to taste.

This is using Rails 5 `left_outer_join`
https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html

But the same thing can be done before Rails 5, using `joins`
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins

```
Announcement.left_outer_joins(:users_groups).where(users_groups: { user_id: current_user.id }).uniq
```

This will get all the announcements that have user groups, and then filter them with the current user ID.

You could put this in the controller and assign it to a variable, or you could make a scope in your model, or a myriad of other options. Good luck!

Comment: But there is  no association between `Announcements` and `UserGroups`, theres one between `Group` and `Announcement`, but no direct association to `UserGroup`. And thanks for telling me that theres should be `UserGroup`, and after 4 days just saw taht there is typo in announcement...

Comment: Ok I've found answer for my problem `Announcement.left_outer_joins(group: :user_groups).where('user_groups.user_id = ?', current_user.id)`, but I need ask one thing should I do method for `annoucement.exp_date >= Date.today` or should I use it on view?